# displaying label and select in the following order

Tags: html, css

```
<label for="adults">Adults</label> 
<select name="audits">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10+">10+</option>
</select> 
<label for="children">Children</label> 
<select name="audits">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10+">10+</option>
</select>
```

How to display label and select as the followings?

```
+------------+    +----------------+
|label       |    |label           |
+------------+    +----------------+
+------------+    +----------------+
|select      |    |select          |
+------------+    +----------------+
```

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/kVFdW/1/

Comment: without touching up markup, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Surround each `label` and `select` group in a `<div>` and in CSS you can `display: block` the `<label>` and `<select>` then `float: left` the `<div>`.

```
<style>
    div { float: left; }
    label, select { display: block; }
</style>

<div>
<label for="adults">Adults</label> 
<select name="audits">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10+">10+</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<label for="children">Children</label> 
<select name="audits">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10+">10+</option>
</select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="l-one">
<label for="adults">Adults</label>
<select name="audits">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10+">10+</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="l-two">
<label for="children">Children</label>
<select name="audits">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10+">10+</option>
</select>
</div>
```

after adding div give to fix width of that `<div>` and give `lable` to `dispaly:block` and also give `dispaly:block` to `<select>`

Comment: wrapping with div I can do that but I'm searching for this without wrapping with div or touching markup just using css. Any techniques?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After seeing that you don't want to add any additional markup, I may have a solution for you. You'll be re-ordering your markup slightly, but it will retain its semantic value.

One quick note: the `for` attribute in your `label` tag should match the `name` attribute in your `select` tags. I've changed the HTML to reflect that.

HTML:

```
<label for="adults">Adults</label> 
<label for="children">Children</label> 
<select name="adults">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10+">10+</option>
</select>
<select name="children">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10+">10+</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
label, select {display: inline-block; float: left; width: 150px; margin: 0px 5px;}
select[name="adults"] {clear: both}
```